# Не сохраняется элемент массива в сессии PHP

Tags: php, сессия

у меня есть корзина с товарами, я делаю проверку при добавлении товара на его наличие в корзине, если он существует - увеличивается количество добавленного товара.

```
  if(isset($_POST['add'])){
    echo "<script>window.location='shop.php'</script>";
    if(isset($_SESSION['cart'])){

        $item_array_id = array_column($_SESSION['cart'], 'item_id');
        if(!in_array($_GET['id'],$item_array_id)){
            $count = count($_SESSION['cart']);
            $item_array = array(
                'item_id' => $_POST['hidden_id'],
                'item_img' => $_POST['hidden_img'],
                'item_name' => $_POST['hidden_name'],
                'item_price' => $_POST['hidden_price'],
                'item_count' => $_POST['count']
            );

            $_SESSION['cart'][$count] = $item_array;
            // echo "<script>window.location='shopcart.php'</script>";
        }
        else{

            foreach($_SESSION['cart'] as $keys => $value){
                if($value['item_id'] == $_GET['id']){

                    $value['item_count'] += $_POST['count'];
                    logReq($value['item_count']);
                }
            }

        } 
    }
```

Я попадаю в условие else и все операции отрабатывают, но я сталкиваюсь с тем, что $value['item_count'] не сохраняется.
Как решить этот вопрос?

Comment: Использовать `=> &$value`

Answer (score 0):

Думаю этот код тебе поможет

```
 <?php
    class Cart
    {
        public static function addProduct($id,$count = 1)
        {
            $id = intval($id);
            $productsInCart = array();
            if (isset($_SESSION['products'])) {
                $productsInCart = $_SESSION['products'];
            }
            if (array_key_exists($id, $productsInCart)){
                $productsInCart[$id] += $count;
            } else {
                $productsInCart[$id] = $count;
            }
            $_SESSION['products'] = $productsInCart;

            return self::countItems();
        }
        public static function countItems()
        {
            if (isset($_SESSION['products'])) {
                $count = 0;
                foreach ($_SESSION['products'] as $id => $quantity) {
                    $count = $count + $quantity;
                }
                return $count;
            } else {
                return 0;
            }
        }
        public static function getProducts()
        {
            if (isset($_SESSION['products'])) {
                return $_SESSION['products'];
            }
            return false;
        }
        public static function clear()
        {
            if (isset($_SESSION['products'])) {
                unset($_SESSION['products']);
            }
        }
        public static function deleteProduct($id)
        {
            $productsInCart = self::getProducts();
            unset($productsInCart[$id]);
            $_SESSION['products'] = $productsInCart;
        }

    }
```

https://webzone.kz/kz/publication/php-session